# How to nest Solution Folders in IWizard implementation in VSTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm implementing an IWizard to create a Visual Studio multi-project template.  My solution groups projects in a number of solution folders, and it's no problem to do this as per [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231187%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to nest solution folders.  I can create a whole load of solution folders in the root solution lever just fine, and place different templated projects within those solution folders but I can't see how to create another solution folder inside a solution folder.  Any tips??

Note: because the VSTemplate will create physical directories for each of the logical solution folders and place the different projects physically within those directories on disk that way is not an option, hence why I'm using the IWizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, of course no sooner had I posted this and I figured out how to do it.  I was maintaining a dictionary of solution folders, here's what I did...

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, SolutionFolder>> _solutionFolders = new Dictionary<String, SolutionFolder>();

_solutionFolders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, SolutionFolder>("Api", (SolutionFolder)solution.AddSolutionFolder("Api").Object));

_solutionFolders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, SolutionFolder>("Api.Commands", (SolutionFolder)_solutionFolders.Single(d => d.Key.Equals("Api")).Value.AddSolutionFolder("Commands").Object));
_solutionFolders.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, SolutionFolder>("Api.Queries", (SolutionFolder)_solutionFolders.Single(d => d.Key.Equals("Api")).Value.AddSolutionFolder("Queries").Object));
```